# Doctrine 2.1 - Subselect in FROM?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Ahoi! 
im searching for a way to generate a query like this in DQL

```
SELECT a.allRegistrations, b.allEvents
FROM 
( SELECT count(r0.ID)  AS allRegistrations
  FROM SPRegistration r0 ) a,
( SELECT count(e1.ID) AS allEvents
  FROM SPEvent e1 ) b;
```

when i try to add one of the subselects in the "from" method it ends up with "Error: Class '(' is not defined."

the alternative way for this query would be ....

```
SELECT 
( SELECT count(r0.ID)  AS allRegistrations
  FROM SPRegistration r0 ) AS allRegistrations;
```

iam new to doctrine ... now after hours of searching, i want to ask here if someone knows how to build such an query.

Comment: I have not used Doctrine 2.1 yet, but in 1.2 they had RawSql builder for doing complex joins. Brief look at the 2.1 docs, looks like Native Sql might be the closest thing. http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently only way to acomplish that is to use:

```
$results = $qb->createQuery('*your select with sub query*')->getResult();
```